# How can I specify which folders/packages are installed in setup.py file with user input?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I'm new to setuptools and I need to create packages based on User Input. This is my file structure:

```
PackagingProject
--src
  --package1
    --__init__.py
  --package2
    --__init__.py
  --package3
    --__init__.py
  --package4
    --__init__.py
  --__init__.py
--pyproject.toml
--setup.py
```

And this is my setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="mmabbas23456",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="Example Author",
    author_email="author@example.com",
    description="A small example package",

    packages= find_packages(
        include=["src",'src*']
        ),
    include_package_data=True,
    python_requires=">=3.6",
)
```

And I use this command to build the distribution:
**"python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel"**

As you all know, this build will include everything in the src folder, including all subfolders (since they all have **init**.py files in them).

What I need to do is to be able to specify which folders I want to include in the package using user input. For instance, if I only want to package package1 and package2, I should be able to do that from the command line. Basically, I'm looking for a way to make the find_packages() function dynamic.

I can only have ONE setup.py file, but I'm not sure if the structure I have right now is right for my problem. Would it be better if the setup.py was located in the src folder to get this job done?

As I said, I'm new to setuptools, so please forgive me if any of the terminologies I used above are incorrect. Please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong anywhere, as it will help me get a better grasp of the topic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).

Comment: @furas Thanks for the feedback, I've edited the post to show the code as text.